# Android OS update system

Tags: android

Suppose I want to make an Android device with some custom OS modifications.

How could I setup an update system that users could use to get the latest version of my modified Android system for their device?

I can't find anything regarding updates in the Android source code.

Comment: Tie up with carriers. They provide OS software updates.

Comment: I can't be very specific but it may or may not be a phone, may or may not be a tablet, or anything else. Is it still possible to have some sort of update system? A website with some xml info, downloadable packages, etc, and have the device check against that? Is such functionality included in the basic Android package or is it always custom written by vendors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check into the update system used by Koush's [Clockwork Recovery / ROM Manager](http://www.koushikdutta.com/2010/02/clockwork-recovery-image.html). The recovery image is open source, and the ROM Manager's update-format specs and resources are as well (although the app itself isn't). The manager can automatically check for updates from a server and download them in the background, then installs them in recovery mode in one click when the user OKs the update.